# Craft 3 installation in git repository

Tags: craft3, install, setup

I am looking for the best way of installing a fresh craft 3 project and making it a git repo.

I tried the following:

Option 1:

- first creating an empty new git repo
- clone the empty repo to my pc using sourcetree
- try and install craft through commandline in that folder

The issue is that craft says the folder isn't empty (which is true because there is a hidden git file inside of the folder of course) and I want craft to be installed in the root of that folder and not in a subfolder.

Option 2:

- I installed a local craft project using command line with success
- then I created a remote repo
- then used git commands (https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) to push the project to the remote repo
- If I then clone the repo to my pc I can't get craft to work, I adjusted the env file and ran composer

I have been messing around so long just to get the craft project up and running in combination with a repo that I need help. I have managed this before but with a lot of detour so I am guessing there is a much better and faster way.

Can anyone explain what the best practices are for creating a craft project in a repo?

Comment: "If I then clone the repo to my pc I can't get craft to work, I adjusted the env file and ran composer" Might be misunderstanding, but why would you need to clone the repo if you've already got it installed locally and connected to github as a remote?